# "Process finished with exit code -2147483645" Pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm, exit-code

I ran Python 3.6.6 Deep Learning with Pycharm 2019.1.3. The process was set at maximum 651 episode and it stopped at episode 368 with this message "Process finished with exit code -2147483645". 
I searched through Google but there's not even a result. Anyone knows about the code? Please help!

Comment: It would be useful to see the whole stack trace. Also, if the issue happens in PyCharm only (e.g., not reproducible from the system terminal with the same interpreter), then it's likely to be a PyCharm-specific issue. For instance, https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-29872

Comment: @Sergey K. : I really appriciated those. 
I must add this: I've already known that this error came off from less ability of my hardware system. Because, every time I run the program with setting up to 367 episodes or exact 368 episodes, rewards will come out perpectly. Everytime, even with episode setting from 368 up, after the last line of results this will appeared "Process finished with exit code -2147483645", and I can read and print out results as well. I  need to understand this error code in details for further conversion (I aimed the goal up to 1500 episodes).

Comment: Did you try reinstalling python? Also are you on 32 or 64 bit?

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to guess what exactly the problem is. But as I experienced the same exit code while doing some file conversions which include plotting with `matplotlib`, so your error is likely to come from this. As Sergey K. mentioned in his comment, the issue is probably PyCharm-related.

There, others pointed out that it helps to switch the backend of `matplotlib`. This can be done by adding the following line right after importing `matplotlib`:

```
matplotlib.rcParams['backend'] = 'QT4Agg'
```

(see https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-29872#focus=streamItem-27-2927779-0-0 )

Answer (score 0):

Mmmm... I dont know about the error. But given the fact that it starts and works well for 368 episodes... I would aim that is some lack of memory related problem.

I would run it several times, if it crash after a similar number of episodes I'd try with more memory.

Hope this helps even just a little bit.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. As my comment to Sergey K., I think Python deverlopers may know about this error code because programs only say what developers wanted them to say.

Comment: now I had a new system, which support 32Gb of memory, stronger CPU and GPU. I've checked with the process during simulation running, CPU cost less than 6%, RAM 20%, GPU almost 50%. This error appeared once again at episode 368th. What the hell. "Process finished with exit code -2147483645".

Comment: As @Sergey K. commented, maybe is a pycharm issue? Try to run it outside of Pycharm.